# C++ friend pointer to function

Tags: c++, windows-8.1, c++-cx

I have a reference class:

```
public ref class class1 sealed
{
    bool (*pointer_to_function)(args);
}
bool function1(args);
//inside of class1 functions
pointer_to_function = &function1;
```

How can I pass to `function1` reference to `class1` to access all data (including private) in `class1`?
If `args == "class1^ args"`, `function1` became full of errors.
Also, I can't set `pointer_to_function` as friend to class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  bool (*pointer_to_function)(args);
```

That is a C function pointer declaration.  Keep in mind that your "class1" can be used by code that does not know beans about C.  Like Javascript or VB.NET.  So this is not possible and the compiler complains, you must use a *delegate* instead.  Delegates are syntax sugar provided by C++/CX to declare function pointers that can work across many languages.  They are more powerful than C function pointers, they can also call instance methods of a class.

A simple example:

```
namespace Foo {
    public delegate void mycallback(int arg);

    public ref class class1 sealed {
    public:
        property mycallback^ pointer_to_function;
    };
}
```

And if you want to initialize it in C++ code then you'd write something like this:

```
ref class Bar {
private:
    Foo::class1^ obj;
    void callbackFunction(int arg) { }
public:
    Bar() : obj(ref new Foo::class1) {
        obj->pointer_to_function = ref new Foo::mycallback(this, &Bar::callbackFunction);
    }
};
```

Do keep the [event keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4b612y2s.aspx) in mind.

Comment: my pointer_to_function is private member, so i dont need to care about other languages. And c-like pointers more easy for use, i just need assign a function and it is all. The problem is Visual Studio behave when two header files include each other, so i wondered if i can just make function1 is friend which can just access private class members

Comment: Well, making it private is not a problem.  It appears you accidentally made it public.